# c++ win32 get system volume accelerator

Tags: c++, winapi, accelerator

is it possible to detect which keys are used for a system volume accelerator in win32 using c++? For example: if the user presses fn + key up (and this is also the key combination to change the system volume), i would like to detect this event and response to it.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/22975916/2877364

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is handled by the machine's BIOS.  It produces a keystroke, VK_VOLUME_DOWN or VK_VOLUME_UP virtual key.  DefWindowProc handling of that WM_KEYDOWN message produces WM_APPCOMMAND, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP/DOWN.  DefWindowProc handling of that message adjusts the volume.

Comment: Actually, `DefWindowProc` handling of that message forwards `WM_APPCOMMAND` to Explorer, and Explorer adjusts the volume. If you want to override the volume buttons in your app, respond to the `WM_APPCOMMAND` message.

Comment: @Raymond - aren't you going too fast?  DefWindowProc handling of WM_APPCOMMAND on a toplevel window invokes the shell hook afaik.  If WM_KEYDOWN handling sends WM_APPCOMMAND straight to Explorer then there's no way to respond to it.

Comment: Yeah, the `WM_APPCOMMAND` goes to Explorer via a shell hook. The point was that it's Explorer that changes the volume, not `DefWindowProc`. The distinction is not significant to this question, but it affects similar questions.

Comment: but the messages WM_APPCOMMAND and WM_KEYDOWN are sent only when the application has focus. How can i detect this keys even if the application doesn't have focus?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible generally. The fn-keys are usually handled by the BIOS-SMM-ACPI whatever, and that is not accesible to user programs.

Maybe, if it were translated to the standard multimedia volume-up key, you could get that, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Answer (score 0):

see this post...
http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/21252-change-volume/

Comment: The OP is asked how to detect keypresses that lead to system volume changes, not how to modify the system volume.